# Can I connect adapt a laptop's mini displayport to a monitor's hdmi port and get 2560 x 1440 resolution?

Tags: display, video, hdmi, mini-displayport

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad W530 with a mini displayport (mini DP) port and a monitor with HDMI as well as dual-link DVI-D (digital).  I know that I can get an active adapter and go from the laptop's mini displayport to the monitor's dual-link DVI-D port, *but can I use a mini-DP to HDMI adapter and get the monitor's supported resolution of 2560 x 1440?*  (This resolution is supported by the laptop's video card.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, probably not.  The [video specifications are here](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/pd024683#vid) (which include everything but HDMI).

- DisplayPort 2560x1600@60Hz
- VGA 2048x1536@75Hz
- DVI (single-link) 1920x1200@60Hz

Unless a laptop supports *Dual-mode* DisplayPort (aka DP++), an HDMI adapter is [typically](http://www.startech.com/AV/Displayport-Converters/Mini-DisplayPort-to-HDMI-Cable-Adapter-Converter~MDP2HDMI) limited to 1920x1200.

Comment: That's the spec doc I've been looking for, thank you!  This is a really dumb question, but the max resolutions they are stating for each display type are for the monitor side, not the PC side, right?  I guess this is an obvious 'yes' since the W530 has display port only...  But I figured I'd ask to make sure.

Comment: I see what you mean - most google results show hdmi adapters going up to 1920 only with a few exceptions.  Think this http://www.amazon.com/Accell-B086B-008B-2-UltraAV-DisplayPort-Adapter/dp/B00DOZHL82 would work?

Comment: W530 has a VGA port.  Any Mini DisplayPort adapter will work the same in your situation, since the W530 doesn't support DP++.

Comment: the W530 has a mini DP also.  Please clarify what you are saying about vga?

Comment: @Emilio You said, "W530 has display port only".  I was merely pointing out that it has VGA as well.

Comment: Gotcha, whoops my bad.  I wish it let me edit the comment.  Anyway, what do you think about the Accell adapter I linked to?

Comment: @Emilio We don't do product recommendations here.  But I did say, "any will work the same".

Comment: I have all the T/W520 and T/W530, and for all of them, the mini-DP ports have a D++ next to them.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you can. Most DisplayPort-HDMI adapters however are *not active*, meaning they rely on the graphics card to output HDMI instead of DisplayPort—[Dual Mode DisplayPort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Dual-mode) AKA DisplayPort++.

With HDMI, there are typically two limits: You graphics card most likely does not support anything greater than 1920x1200 over HDMI. The same goes for your display (**which model?**): It probably won’t accept anything above this resolution via HDMI.

The only possible solution is an *active adapter*. It takes DisplayPort input and outputs Dual-link DVI. These adapters are very expensive (about $ 90) and always need additional power—typically drawn from a USB port.

Examples:

- [Accell UltraAV B087B-002B DisplayPort/DVI-D Dual-Link Adapter (Black)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002ISVI3U)
- [Apple Mini MB571Z/A DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001IF252C)

Comment: The link to the W530 specs that @Jason provided unfortunately doesn't show HDMI.  My monitor is a qx2710 led evolution ii multi true10 se   http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA4JH1NB1871.

Comment: @Emilio Hm, so basically a no-name device. Unfortunately, I found no information on the maximum resolution it accepts via HDMI, though it claims to support HDMI 1.4a. Your notebook doesn’t require a HDMI port to support DP++. It’s an internal “connection”. Still, it won’t be enough, as hinted at by the Single-Link DVI resolution.

Comment: Buy by definition dual link DVI (DVI-D) supports that higher resolution, no?  Also what do you mean by internal connection?

Comment: DP++ ports detect when a passive adapter is connected. It then switches to HDMI internally (on the GPU). This means there is no DisplayPort signal at all. A Dual Link DVI adapter is the safest way to go.

Comment: Gotcha.  There goes $90!  I should have spent the add'l $50 and gotten the model with the native dp!!  haha

Comment: The $90 device worked.  :(

Comment: Why do you need to go with DVI?  What about an *active* DP to HDMI adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should work. Display port supports HDMI through a dongle. http://www.vesa.org/displayport-developer/faq/

Comment: I discovered this doesn't work because I think in this configuration the max resolution is 1920x1080.